# Magento 2 rewrite product collection for toolbar and filter in product listing

Tags: magento2, product-collection, listing

Which model use in toolbar and filter on product listing page? I need to rewrite collection, but can't find it.
I use event

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_block_product_list_collection">
        <observer name="my_filter instance="Dv\MyFilter\Observer\Myfilter"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Code in observer

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{

    $event    = $observer->getEvent();
    $event->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('my_attr', ['eq' => '1']);;

}
```

and it works only for product collections in listing. How I can update collection for toolbar and filter navigation?

Comment: describe what you have try.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i edit and explain it in answer